# webcam streaming on mobile phone

Tags: streaming, webcam, mobile-phone

I'm stuck on a project I have I need to find a way to stream my home webcam onto my mobile phone, in this case on a Blackberry bold 9700, also I have an I pod touch 2.0.  the problem I keep coming across is that every program I find askes for money, I am looking for a way to do this for free, ive been trying using vlc but have so far been unable to get the stream to work, any help would be great

Comment: What exactly did you try already?

Comment: i tried to stream over http on vlc and transcoding it using h263 as this is viewable on the blackberry but cant seem to get it to work, im a bit of a newbie at this so am struggling a bit

Answer (score 1):

ustream has a free app for the iphone. it should work for the ipod touch.

Answer (score 1):

webcamxp - http://www.webcamxp.com/home.aspx

Compatible with Windows XP, Vista, 7, 2003 and 2008 Server.

Answer (score 1):

Try [JumiCam](http://www.jumitech.com/index.php?page=cam) for iOSor Android devices. Compatible with Windows XP/Vista/7 32 & 64 Bit.

> JumiCam is a monitoring & surveillance system which streams PC webcam directly to your iPhone/iPod/Android from an unlimited number of cameras. JumiCam Lite is a free version that is limited to local WiFi only (no 3G / Edge / Distant WiFi hotspots)